# The "print_candidate" function isnt working. Is it a logical error?

Tags: c, cs50

This is the code for a plurality voting program. The issue is that the for loop in the last function isnt working properly. The output is here:

$ make plurality

clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    plurality.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o plurality

~/pset3/plurality/ $ ./plurality Alice Bob

Number of voters: 3

Vote: Alice

Vote: Bob

Vote: Alice

Bob  votes: 2

This is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(int);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (vote(name)==-false)
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner(candidate_count);
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    int check=0;
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,candidates[i].name))
        {
             candidates[i].votes++;
             break;
        }
        else
         check++;

    }
    // TODO
    if(check!=9)
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(int ccount)
{
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    for (int j=0;j<ccount;j++)
    {
        if(i<candidates[j].votes)
        {
            i=candidates[j].votes;
            count = j;
        }
    }
    // TODO
    printf("%s  votes: %i \n", candidates[count].name,i);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) C11 standard, and the documentation of your compiler [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/)..) Stack-Overflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website

Comment: Seems like you can do alot more debugging on your own before throwing it to Stack Overflow. For example have you actually examined the `candidates` array in a debugger or dumped it out to see if it is correct? `if(strcmp(name,candidates[i].name))` should be `if(strcmp(name,candidates[i].name) == 0)`

Comment: @Omar Your code might even crash if an invalid voter name is entered. ``for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)`` this is dangerous, you are not initializing all the structs every time.

Comment: And where is ``print_candidate()`` function !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I can readily see the following mistakes:

- **`if (vote(name)==-false)`**

`cs50.h` gets the `false` definition from `stdbool.h`. Is it necessary to have `-false`, won't `false` suffice?

- **`for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)`**

`candidate candidates[MAX];` is globally declared, so the uninitialized element's default to `0`. If your `candidate_count` is less then `MAX` then `strcmp(name,candidates[i].name)` returns `SIGSEGV` if you try to access any struct whose index is `>=` to `canditate_count` and your program crashes. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)`.

- **`if(strcmp(name,candidates[i].name))`**

If the string values of `name` and `candidates[i].name` are equal then `strcmp()` returns `0`, you might want to have this `if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)`.